# nested classes in Python

Tags: python, class, nested-class

Dealing with classes (nested etc) does not look easy in **Python**, **surprisingly**! The following problem appeared to me recently and took several hours (try, search ...) without success. I read most of SO related links but none of them has pointed the issue presented here!

```
#------------------------------------
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
        print self.a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 'b'
        A.a = 'a_b'
        print self.b, A.a
#------------------------------------
class C:
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = 'a'
            print self.a

    class B(A):
        def __init__(self):
            self.b = 'b'
            A.a = 'a_b'
            print self.b, A.a
#------------------------------------
#------------------------------------
>>> c1 = A()
a
>>> c1.a
'a'
>>> c2 = B()
b 
>>> c2.a, c2.b
('a_b', 'b')
>>> c3 = C()
>>> c4 = c3.A()
a
>>> c4.a
'a'
>>> c5 = c3.B()
b a_b
>>> c5.b
'b'
>>> c5.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'a'
```

Where is the problem in the code?
**AND**
In both cases it seems that when B(A) is initialized A() is not initialized. What is the solution for this issue? Note that the term `A.__init__()` being called inside B()'s `__init__()` does not work!

**Updates:**

```
class Geometry:
    class Curve:
        def __init__(self,c=1):
            self.c = c                          #curvature parameter
            print 'Curvature %g'%self.c
            pass                                #some codes

    class Line(Curve):
        def __init__(self):
            Geometry.Curve.__init__(self,0)     #the key point
            pass                                #some codes

g = Geometry()
C = g.Curve(0.5)
L = g.Line()
```

which results in:

```
Curvature 0.5
Curvature 0
```

what I was looking for.

Comment: "... `A.__init__()` being called inside B()'s `__init__()` does not work!" Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: ditto. how did your call of `A.__init__()` in `B.__init__()` look like?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The solution for the problem now is found. That's great just after a few hours. You can find your point in the update section of the question.

Comment: @soulcheck see my comment above for Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

Comment: @Supporter it would be much simpler if instead of the outer Geometry class you just created a module called 'geometry'. Then you get exactly the same grouping but without the complications of the nested class: `import geometry as g` `c = g.Curve(0.5)` `l = g.Line()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code executed in a method runs in the local scope of that method. If you access an object that is not in this scope, Python will look it up in the global/module scope, **NOT** in the class scope or the scope of any enclosing class!

This means that:

```
A.a = 'a_b'
```

inside `C.B.__init__` will set the class attribute of the global `A` class, not `C.A` as you probably intended. For that you would have to do this:

```
C.A.a = 'a_b'
```

Also, Python will not call parent methods if you override them in subclasses. You have to do it yourself.

The scoping rules mean that if you wanted to call the `__init__` method of the parent class inside `C.B.__init__`, it has to look like this:

```
C.A.__init__(self)
```

and NOT like this:

```
A.__init__(self)
```

which is probably what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks. I could solve the problem with your **key point** of `scoping rules`. The full solution was added as updates.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes seems so unpythonic, even if considered as factories. But to answer your question: There simply is no c5.a (instance of C.B). In the init-method of C.B you add to the CLASS C.A an attribute a, but not to C.B! The class A does already have an attribute a, if instantiated! But the object of class B (and even the class) doesn't!

You must also keep in mind, that `__init__` is not an constructor like in C++ or Java! The "real constructor" in python would be `__new__`. `__init__` just initializes the instance of a class!

```
class A:
    c = 'class-attribute'
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 'instance-attribute'
```

So in this example c is a class-attribute, where i is an attribute of the instance.

Even more curios, is your attempt to add an attribute to the baseclass at the moment of the instantiation of the child-class. You are not getting a "late" inheritance-attribute that way.
You simply add to the class A an additional attribute, which surprises me to even work. I guess you are using python 3.x?

The reason for this behaviour? Well, i guess it has to do with pythons neat feature that in python definitions are [executed](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function)(AFAIK).

The same reason why:

```
def method(lst = []):
```

is almost ever a bad idea. the deafult-parameter gets bound at the moment of the definition and you won't generate a new list-object every-time you call the method, but reusing the same list-object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you can see in update section of the question, sometime nested classes make the programming more structured and easy to handle.