# Why are class nodes not saving children outside of method call? Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, graph-algorithm

**The Repo:**
https://github.com/icarus612/mazeRunner-PY/tree/stack-overflow

**The issue:** I don't know why the the nodes are not saving their children outside the runner method call.

**The project:** Im building a maze runner with several classes, a node class for storing spots in the maze, a maze class to take in mazes and evaluate what are walls and what are spaces, and a runner class to map the maze, find if there is a route possible and then solve for the route. There is also a solver script to take in command line inputs. originally I had built a working "runner" but it wasn't giving the proper route, so I went back to the drawing board (if someone can tell me way the runner isn't giving the proper route that would be cool too but thats not the question at hand)

**Why are the nodes not saving there children outside the method?**

The code here will be an abridged version just for what the issue Im running into is.

**Node class:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value 
        self.children = []
        self.visited = []

    def add_visited(self, node):
        self.visited.append(node)   

    def add_child(self, child_node):
        self.children.append(child_node) 

    def add_path(self, node_path):
        if not self.path:
            self.path = node_path
        else:
            self.path = self.path if len(self.path) < len(node_path) else node_path

    def remove_child(self, child_node):
        self.children.discard(child_node)
```

**Runner Class:**

```
class Runner:
    def __init__(self, maze):
        self.open_nodes = []
        self.visited = []
        self.start = None
        self.end = None
        self.maze = maze
        self.completed = False
        self.mapped_maze = []
        self.node_paths = []
        self.find_end_points()
        self.get_open_nodes()

    def get_open_nodes(self):
        p = self.maze.layout
        for x in range(len(p)):
            for y in range(len(p[x])):
                if p[x][y] != self.maze.wall_char:
                    self.open_nodes.append(Node((x, y)))
        for i in self.open_nodes:
            self.look_around(i)
            print(i.children) #should print something !and does!:)

    def find_end_points(self):
        for x in range(len(self.maze.layout)):
            for y in range(len(self.maze.layout[x])):
                p = self.maze.layout[x][y]
                if p == self.maze.start_char:
                    self.start = Node((x, y))
                elif p == self.maze.end_char:
                    self.end = Node((x, y))

    def look_around(self, node):
        for i in self.open_nodes:
            if i.value[0]-1 == node.value[0] and i.value[1] == node.value[1]:
                node.add_child(i)
            if i.value[0]+1 == node.value[0] and i.value[1] == node.value[1]:
                node.add_child(i)
            if i.value[1]-1 == node.value[1] and i.value[0] == node.value[0]:
                node.add_child(i)
            if i.value[1]+1 == node.value[1] and i.value[0] == node.value[0]:
                node.add_child(i)       

    def make_node_paths(self, point=None):
        if point == None:
            point = self.start
        print(point.value, point.children)
        for i in point.children:
            if i.value not in point.visited:
                point.add_visited(point.value)
                if point.value == self.end.value:
                    self.node_paths.append(point.path)
                    self.completed = True

                self.make_node_paths(i)
```

**Maze Class:**

```
class Maze:
    def __init__ (self, layout=None, start_char="s", end_char="e", wall_char="#", open_char=" ", build=(10, 10)):
        self.wall_char = wall_char
        self.start_char = start_char
        self.end_char = end_char
        self.open_char = open_char
        self.layout = layout
        if layout:
            self.width = len(layout[0])
            self.height = len(layout)
        else:
            self.build_new(build[0], build[1])
```

**Solver script:**

```
maze = Maze(build=(20, 20)) 

runner = Runner(maze)
print(runner.start.value, runner.start.children) #point that should be logging something !but doesnt!:(
runner.make_node_paths()
complete = "Yes" if runner.completed else "No"
print(f"Is maze possible? {complete}")
```

**Console for the two print statements:**

```
[<node.Node object at 0x101060780>] #what runner.start.children should be
[<node.Node object at 0x1010604a8>, <node.Node object at 0x100d253c8>]
[<node.Node object at 0x1010604e0>, <node.Node object at 0x1010606d8>]
[<node.Node object at 0x1010604a8>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25400>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d25470>]
[<node.Node object at 0x1010601d0>, <node.Node object at 0x100d254a8>]
[<node.Node object at 0x1010604e0>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25518>]
[<node.Node object at 0x1010606d8>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25438>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25588>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d25400>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25470>]
[<node.Node object at 0x101060710>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25438>, <node.Node object at 0x100d255c0>]
[<node.Node object at 0x101060780>, <node.Node object at 0x100d254e0>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d254a8>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25518>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d253c8>, <node.Node object at 0x100d254e0>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25550>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d25518>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25588>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d25400>, <node.Node object at 0x100d25550>]
[<node.Node object at 0x100d25470>]

(1, 1) [] #runner.start.value and what runner.start.children comes in as
```

**other notes:**
I haven't included some of the runner class and most of the solver script that gets inputs and most of the maze script that builds a maze. The issue Im having is that when i make nodes and give those nodes children the save in the initial method, as you can see logged out, but then when i try to log it out in the next line of my solver function i get diddly squat. I don't even know what type of issue Im looking at here. Is this memory or something wrong with the way i'm saving them? i tried to switch them from in sets to in arrays but that didn't work, either. It seems to work if its all inside the same method but not if its in 2 separate methods. its like the its losing those children after it exits the method.

**Update:**

I found this link which sort of answers my question without Really giving an answer: [nested classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775246/nested-classes-in-python?rq=1)

after reading this Im wondering if i need to make the classes extend each other in some way? it provides insight into what might be going on without really giving an answer on how i could fix my issue, and Im not working with extended classes. I have tried finding ways to make sure the copy is a deep copy but even when using copy.deepcopy the code stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in how i was saving self.start and self.end in the find_end_points function.

```
    def find_end_points(self):
        def check(node_val):
            if node_val not in [i.value for i in self.open_nodes]:
                node = Node(node_val) 
            else:
                for i in self.open_nodes:
                    if i.value == node_val:
                        node = i
            return node
        for x in range(len(self.maze.layout)):
            for y in range(len(self.maze.layout[x])):
                p = self.maze.layout[x][y]
                if p == self.maze.start_char:
                    self.start = check((x, y))
                elif p == self.maze.end_char:
                    self.end = check((x, y))
```

is the new function and now i get the proper start and end values as well as the children that were saved to them. This is not an issue with global or local variable saving in a method.